# How to turn off reload when JS function starts in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

I made this clipboard copy function. it work at my Laravel. But there are some problem. I can copy but when I click the COPY button current page reload. 
Another thngs is I would like to make cool design like Github'S "Clone with HTTPS" under "Use Git or checkout with SVN using the web URL. " sentence
at small window's image.
Could you teach me what is wrong my code please?

Laravel's form is here I need to write like this but when click the clipboard copy I don't want to go nextpage

```
  <form action="{{ url('nextpage') }}" method="post">
```

index.blade.php

```
<p><span class="js-copytext">{{$post_data['somedata']}}</span></p>
<p><button class="js-copybtn">copy</button></p>
```

js file

```
<script>

var copyEmailBtn = document.querySelector('.js-copybtn');
copyEmailBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    var copyText = document.querySelector('.js-copytext');
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(copyText);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    try {

        var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
        var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
        console.log('Copy command was ' + msg);

    } catch(err) {
        console.log('error');
    }

    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `event.preventDefault()` inside your handler.

```
copyEmailBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // The rest of your code...
});
```

Comment: Dear @Lawless Thank you very much! It worked. I appreciate! Do me a favor Could you teach me little more. Can I change design github clipboard copy ? like simply add CDN ?

Comment: @machagr you are welcome. However I am unclear as to what you're asking for next, because if I test your code (without Laravel) it works - https://jsfiddle.net/Lawlesss/vuf6z5r2/1/

Comment: Dear @Lawless Thank you for answering me. Your code is perfect. it works very well. I asked totally diffrent things It's about Design. I would like to make design like github's "Clone with HTTPS" green button and text field. You might know how to change design? so I asked^^